# UITabbar is shortened

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

[image]

I have no idea why.

This is the code:

```
self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"CategoryTabBarActive"];
self.tabBar.items= allTabBar;
self.tabBar.selectedItem= self.tabBar.items[lastSelectedCategoryNumber];

self.categoryScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tabBar.items.count * 91, self.categoryScrollView.contentSize.height);//The width of tab bar is set up here
CGRect tabBarFrame= self.tabBar.frame;
tabBarFrame.size.width=self.categoryScrollView.contentSize.width;
self.tabBar.frame=tabBarFrame;
self.tabBar.backgroundImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"CategoryTabBar"];
```

And the image height is 55. I wonder if the image goes up or down. I see no code that does that. Location of foreground image and text is correct.

This is the location of UITabBar

```
(lldb) po self.tabBar
<UITabBar: 0x14b2c7f0; frame = (0 0; 1820 55); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x14b2b470>>

(lldb) po self.tabBar.superview
<UIScrollView: 0x14b2b050; frame = (0 0; 320 55); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14b2b540>; layer = <CALayer: 0x14b2a880>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

(lldb) po self.tabBar.superview.superview
error: property 'superview' not found on object of type 'id'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po [self.tabBar.superview superview]
<UIScrollView: 0x14b2f1b0; frame = (0 0; 320 55); autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14b2f440>; layer = <CALayer: 0x14b2f380>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

(lldb) po [[self.tabBar.superview superview]superview]
<UIView: 0x14932220; frame = (0 39; 320 55); autoresize = LM+RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x14932280>>

(lldb) po [[self.tabBar.superview superview]superview].backgroundColor
error: no known method '-superview'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po [[[self.tabBar.superview superview]superview] backgroundColor]
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 0

(lldb) po [[[self.tabBar.superview superview]superview] superview]
<UIView: 0x14933450; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x149334b0>>
```

Comment: is your auto layout turned off?

Comment: We don't use auto layout.

Comment: This tab bar is  near the top of the screeen

Comment: This happened to me a few times as well, after removing the auto layout. It is mostly to do with the Autosizing constraints in the Size Inspector for each of the subviews in the tab bar, and the tab bar itself. Try playing with those, and see if it helps you fix the problem.

Comment: I think it works fine in 7.0

Comment: I do not control subviews in the tab bar. It's controlled by IOS right?